# How to pass complete query as String in repository method as argument and use with the @Query Annotation?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I prepared a query in serviceImplementation ,After that I passed this query  as method argument  of
presentDaySummarySmscWise(String finalQuery)   Repository method.
In Repository Interface ,I passed this query  with @Query Annotaion like shown in code.

**strong text**
//ServiceImplementation class

@Service

public class ErrorCodeServiceImpl implements ErrorCodeService {

@Autowired

```
ErrorCodeRepository errorCodeRepo;
```

@Override

```
public List<Object[]> errorCodeDefaultSummary() {

String finalQuery="select smsc,vf_reason_code from reason_code_report where 
log_date='2021-05-27'";

List<Object[]> result =   errorCodeRepo.presentDaySummarySmscWise(finalQuery);

return result;
```

}
**`strong text`**
//Repository

@Repository

public interface ErrorCodeRepository extends JpaRepository<ErrorCodeReportEntity, ErrorCodeReportKeys>{

@Query(value=":query",nativeQuery=true)

List<Object[]> presentDaySummarySmscWise(String query);

}

Comment: You cannot pass a query to a repository method unless you are willing to write a custom repository fragment. Could you please explain why the query needs to be passed as an argument in the first place?

Comment: actually , I need a dynamic query in which no of columns can be differ, so i prepared a query based on logic and passed as argument .  And in native query to access argument value we use ":argument_variable ".  So whole query will be replaced by my passed query.  I also tried  custom repository  fragment but it doesn't work.

Comment: If you just want to execute arbitrary queries, JPA repositories are not the correct facility to use.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot replace arbitrary fragments of the query using a query parameter. Only very specific sections of the query allow parameters.

If you need dynamic queries, Specifications or QueryDSL is what you want.

Comment: can you provide any link  or code snippets that suits to my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Query("#{[0]}")
 @WithConsistency(QueryScanConsistency.REQUEST_PLUS)
 List<Employee> findByDateAllQuery(String query);
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I believe you need to add `@Param("query")` into your argument in the repository.

`List<Object[]> presentDaySummarySmscWise(@Param("query") String query);`

Comment: not working, exception from jpa at parameter level.