# No property [MethodName] found for type [EntityName] while executing custom jpa repository method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I've need to prepare a query in ServiceImpl ,as based on some logic the query can be differ by no. of columns. so  I decided to prepare a custom JPA Repository but getting some error.

Before this to fulfill my requirement I tried this [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67726910/how-to-pass-complete-query-as-string-in-repository-method-as-argument-and-use-wi?noredirect=1#comment119710967_67726910) , please check .But I think JPA doesn't allow like this. So I tried Custom JPA Repository and getting error.

**

```
 Entity class


  @SuppressWarnings("serial")
 
  @Entity
  
  @Getter
  
  @Setter
  
  @Table(name = "REASON_CODE_REPORT",schema="automation") 
  @IdClass(ErrorCodeReportKeys.class)
  public class ErrorCodeReportEntity
  {
        @Id
        private String smsc;
        
        @Id
        private String userid;
        
        @Id
        private String smsc_userid;
        
        @Id
        private String operator;
        
        @Id
        private String circle;
        
        @Id
        private Date log_date;
        
        @Id
        private Integer log_hour;
        
        @Id
        private Integer log_min;
        
        @Id
        private  Integer vf_reason_code;
        
        @Id
        private  Integer smsc_reason_code;

        private Integer count;
        
        private Timestamp create_date;

  }
```

**

ServiceImpl

```
@Override
    public List<Object[]> errorCodeDefaultSummary(ErrorCodeReportDTO errorCodeReportDTO) {
 
          String finalQuery="select smsc,userid from ErrorCodeReportEntity where log_date='2021-05-27'";
      List<Object[]> result =   errorCodeRepo.presentDaySummarySmscWise(finalQuery);
      
     
        return result;
}
```

Custom JPA Interface

```
public interface ErrorCodeCustom {

      List<Object[]> presentDaySummarySmscWise(String query);
        
}
```

Implementation of ErrorCodeCustomImpl

```
public class ErrorCodeCustomImpl implements ErrorCodeCustom{

    @Autowired
    private EntityManager entityManager;
    
    
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<Object[]> presentDaySummarySmscWise(String query) {
        
     final  String finalQuery=query.toString();
        
       List<Object[]>  result= entityManager.createQuery(finalQuery).getResultList();
        
        
        
        return result;
    }

}
```

The Final Jpa Repository that implements our CustomRepository

```
@Repository
public interface ErrorCodeRepository extends JpaRepository<ErrorCodeReportEntity, ErrorCodeReportKeys>,ErrorCodeCustom
{
}
```

I don't know why i'm getting following errors

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.valuefirst.repository.ErrorCodeCustom.presentDaySummarySmscWise(java.lang.String)! No property presentDaySummarySmscWise found for type ErrorCodeReportEntity!

Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property presentDaySummarySmscWise found for type ErrorCodeReportEntity!
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring was not able to find your implementation ErrorCodeCustomImpl. You should annotate it @Component.

so the exception is there because ErrorCodeRepository extends ErrorCodeCustom and the query generated by your method name is trying to use a property named presentDaySummarySmscWise. Once your ErrorCodeCustomImpl will be injected by Spring the error will be gone.